# custom SVG label style - openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, svg

My goal is to display rotated labels for roads on my openlayers based webmap.
The problem is actually solved (with a custom SVG solution), but i have some problems with the styling of the labels. 
As I using the custom SVG js, 'labelOutlineColor' and 'labelOutlineWidth' (which I use as styleMap parameters) stop doing anything whith the labels. Do I have to implement those parameters into my custom SGV js? And if is that so, how can I do it?

Here is the CustomSGV.js I use:

```
OpenLayers.Renderer.CustomSVG = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG, {   


drawText: function(featureId, style, location) {

    var resolution = this.getResolution();      



    var layer = this.map.getLayer(this.container.id);

    var feature = layer.getFeatureById(featureId);        

    location = (feature.attributes.centroid ? feature.attributes.centroid : location);



    var x = (location.x / resolution + this.left);

    var y = (location.y / resolution - this.top);



    var label = this.nodeFactory(featureId + this.LABEL_ID_SUFFIX, "text");

    var tspan = this.nodeFactory(featureId + this.LABEL_ID_SUFFIX + "_tspan", "tspan");



    label.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);

    label.setAttributeNS(null, "y", -y);

    label.setAttributeNS(null, "pointer-events", "none");



    if (style.angle || style.angle == 0) {        

        var rotate = 'rotate(' + style.angle + ',' + x + "," + -y + ')'; 

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", rotate);

    }

    if (style.fontColor) {

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", style.fontColor);

    }

    if (style.fontFamily) {

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "font-family", style.fontFamily);

    }

    if (style.fontSize) {

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", style.fontSize);

    }

    if (style.fontWeight) {

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "font-weight", style.fontWeight);

    }



    var align = style.labelAlign || "cm";

    label.setAttributeNS(null, "text-anchor",

        OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.LABEL_ALIGN[align[0]] || "middle");



    if (this.isGecko) {

        label.setAttributeNS(null, "dominant-baseline",

            OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.LABEL_ALIGN[align[1]] || "central");

    } else {

        tspan.setAttributeNS(null, "baseline-shift",

            OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.LABEL_VSHIFT[align[1]] || "-35%");

    }



    tspan.textContent = style.label;



    if(!label.parentNode) {

        label.appendChild(tspan);

        this.textRoot.appendChild(label);

    }   

},



CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.CustomSVG"
});
```